# line dividing page vertically

Tags: html, css

I need facebook like time line. The line will be at the center of page dividing page. Here is my html

```
 <div id="top">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class"left"></div>
  <div class="right"><div>

  </div>
```

The div with class left will appear on left side of line and class with right will appear on right side.

I have been looking for some time with no success. Any one has any idea?

Comment: could you provide the image preview or link for your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Use below class on  `<div class="right"></div>`

```
.verticalSeparation {
    border-left: thick solid #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following css on your left class. It will give you a right border with top, bottom and left borders off which should give a line down the center.

```
.left{
border-right:solid;
border-left:none;
border-top:none;
border-bottom:none;
}
```

If this doesn't work, please post your css.

Comment: no it has to be something other than playing with border

Comment: @abc you should explain **why** it has to be something other

Comment: On my facebook timeline, there is no vertical line separating the timeline. The closest thing to a vertical line is the padding they are using to separate the profile div's , timeline, and suggested groups. Are you looking for padding:    padding: 12px;  which adds a small border between elements?

Answer (score -1):

Their are tons of tutorials available on the web using quite simple and understandable code like so http://codyhouse.co/gem/vertical-timeline/. Hope this works out for you.